# How to link specific parent node of a TreeView to a specific file (vb.net/c#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, treeview, treenode

I have a TreeView that has N numeber of Parent Nodes, each with equal number of child nodes, like the following example (City 1, 2, ... are parent nodes; and the child nodes are house, hotel, shop, bank, school);

City1
 - House
 - Hotel
 - Shop
 - Bank
 - School
City2
 - House
 - Hotel
 - Shop
 - Bank
 - School
City3
 - House
 - Hotel
 - Shop
 - Bank
 - School

Now, what I would like to do is to do some operation based on the following rules:

if any child under a particular parent node, say City1, is checked) is checked, the parent node state is checked as well. Thus, I can read information about City1 from a file, say file_index_1.  Since file_index_1 is located, it doesn't matter if another child node from the same parent node is checked.  I need only at least one child node checked to check the parent node and use the corresponding file

if City2 (or any of its child) is checked, file_index_2 is invoked

if CityN (or any of its child) is checked, file_index_N is invoked

if both parent nodes are checked (because a minimum of one child node is checked under each parent node), only the file_index_associated to the parentnode where a child node is being checked.

if for instance City1 is not checked (because no child nod is checked under it), the file-index_1 will not be used.

If no child node is checked under all parent nodes, no file will be invoked.

In the AfterCheck event, I can get the index of the checked parent node with the following code:

Dim nodeIndex As Integer = 0

```
    For k As Integer = 0 To NumberOfParentNodes
        If e.Node.Text = "Specific Parentnode Name, eg. City1" Then
            nodeIndex = e.Node.Index  
            'call a file with the same index as the parentnode index
            'But How about if any childnode is checked even if the parentnode is not checked??
            'And how to get the index of the parent node of a child being checked
        End If
    Next
```

But have difficulties to relate the child.checked => parent.checked.  I hope my intention is understandable.  Can you help how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will be a good starting place for the code you're looking for :

```
Private Sub TreeViewBuilderButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TreeViewBuilderButton.Click

    Dim nd As TreeNode = TestTreeView.Nodes.Add("C1", "City1")
    addChildren(nd)
    nd = TestTreeView.Nodes.Add("C2", "City2")
    addChildren(nd)
    nd = TestTreeView.Nodes.Add("C3", "City3")
    addChildren(nd)

    TestTreeView.ExpandAll()

End Sub

Private Sub addChildren(nd As TreeNode)

    nd.Nodes.Add(String.Concat(nd.Name, "_House"), "House")
    nd.Nodes.Add(String.Concat(nd.Name, "_Hotel"), "Hotel")
    nd.Nodes.Add(String.Concat(nd.Name, "_Shop"), "Shop")
    nd.Nodes.Add(String.Concat(nd.Name, "_Bank"), "Bank")
    nd.Nodes.Add(String.Concat(nd.Name, "_School"), "School")
End Sub

Private Sub TestTreeView_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TestTreeView.AfterCheck
    Try

        If (e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown) Then
            Dim nd As TreeNode = DirectCast(e.Node, TreeNode)

            nd.Parent.Checked = anyChildChecked(nd.Parent)

            Debug.Print(String.Concat("Node: ", nd.Text, " Node Name: ", nd.Name, " Parent: ", nd.Parent.Text, " Parent Name:", nd.Parent.Name))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function anyChildChecked(nd As TreeNode) As Boolean

    For Each ndChild As TreeNode In nd.Nodes
        If ndChild.Checked Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

As an example, I checked City 2 Hotel and then City1 Bank
Debug output is as follows:

> Node: Hotel Node Name: C2_Hotel Parent: City2 Parent Name:C2
>   Node: Bank Node Name: C1_Bank Parent: City1 Parent Name:C1

Comment: thanks. When I uncheck one of the child nodes, the parent node get unchecked even if there are other child nodes still checked.  I have got the same solution and issues under the mouseClick event   with   If e.Node.Checked = True Then   e.Node.Parent.Checked = True  . I still have a question on how to keep the parent node still checked until all child nodes are unchecked??? Because this would help me to control I am still under the same parent node until I get out of it 'when all child nodes are unchecked)

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the 'any checked' scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With the same method above, I did hold the unckeck value of the parent nodes within a text control and that solved the issue